# Error when trying to initialize ParseFacebookUtils

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I am using Parse as the back end for an Android application and everything works fine until I try to use the ParseFacebookUtils to sign up people using facebook.

In my Main class which extends Application I initialize both Parse and Facebook in the oncreate function.

```
 Parse.initialize(this, CloudDataHandler.getAPPLICATION_ID(), CloudDataHandler.getCLIENT_KEY());
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);
```

The error thrown is of the form,

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider

Has anyone encountered such a problem before and if so how did you handle it?

My App's build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.2.jar'])
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'

}

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
}
```

Comment: Encountering exactly the same issue. I'm trying to implement the `ParseUI-Login` module as well and it's a nightmare

Comment: Please put in your app's `build.gradle` file and the `ParseUI-Login`'s `build.gradle` file if you're using it

Comment: I have the same issue, anyone?